# Extracting unique values from Access Table and Creating an array which can be used in a combo box

Tags: vba, excel

I want to be able to extract details from an Access database to my excel workbook. I have created a userform where the user enters the policy number  and then click a command button that should provide a another userform with a dropdown list of all the quotes for that policy

The access database table contains multiple rows for a given quote but I want to be able to extract a list of unique quote ids for the policy from which the user can select the quote they want to load the details for.

Below is an extract from the Access database (table name qteVehicleDetails, database name QuoteDB)

[Database Extract](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiyMz.gif)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim dbQuoteDB As Database
Dim rTemp As Recordset
Dim sSQL As String



Set dbQuoteDB = OpenDatabase(QuoteDB, False, False, "MS Access;PWD=***")

    sSQL = "SELECT qteVehicleDetails.* FROM qteVehicleDetails WHERE (qteVehicleDetails.policyno=" & LoadQuoteDetails.Controls("PolicyNo").Value & " AND qteVehicleDetails.Class=" & LoadQuoteDetails.Controls("Class").Value & ");"
    Set rTemp = dbQuoteDB.OpenRecordset(sSQL)

    Do Until rTemp.EOF

    ???



    rTemp.MoveNext


End Sub
```

I want to be able to extract a list of unique quotes ids for a given policy (you will see from the database extract that there are duplicates)

Then I want to save this as a range which can be used to populate the combo box in the second userform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"SELECT DISTINCT qteVehicleDetails.* FROM qteVehicleDetails WHERE (qteVehicleDetails.policyno=" & LoadQuoteDetails.Controls("PolicyNo").Value & " AND qteVehicleDetails.Class=" & LoadQuoteDetails.Controls("Class").Value & ");"
```

you can try add 'distinct' in your sql script